# Connection to HSM launch error 48

Tags: ssl, hsm

I'm trying to access to a Safenet HSM from my computer, I added my computer how to client and sent the pem file to HSM, all right to here. The problem was when I typed "`vtl verify`", because it launch the following error:

> SSL Connect is failing
>
> Error: Unable to find any Luna SA slots/partitions among registered
>          servers. Ensure this client is assigned partitions on the
>          Luna SA servers, and check the vtl supportInfo command for
>          other possible problems such as unable to ping a server, or
>          missing configuration files.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can solve my problem with the follow steps:

1. Delete all certificates from my computer
2. Delete the server from file configuration
3. Regenerate the certificate from HSM with the command `sysconf
   regenCert <ip_of_hsm>`
4. Run the command `ntls bind eth0`
5. Run all the commands to registry HSM in your computer and append your
   computer into HSM

Then `vtl verify` should run correctly

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution +1. Note that this is rather vendor specific, and that the HSM and SSL tags are not followed by a lot of people (I only check them now and then) so your question was hiding in plain sight. Just in case you were wondering why it received so little attention.

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes, it is necessary to check your firewall rule configuration. On hardware firewalls, such as Cisco ASA, you need to explicitly open port 1792 to "allow" inbound/outbound traffic.

If this port is closed, it will not be able to find the server and you will see this error.